# MySQL query - get sum of counts depending on column

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with actions and question_ids. Each action comes with a score like this:

```
     ACTION       | SCORE
downvote_question |  -1
upvote_question   |  +1
in_cardbox        |  +2
```

I want to query for the question with the highest score but I can't figure it out.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84e26/15

So far my query is:

```
SELECT count(*), l1.question_id, l1.action 
FROM `log` l1
GROUP BY l1.question_id, l1.action
```

which gives me every question_id with all its accumulated actions.

What I want is this:

```
QUESTION_ID | SCORE
     2      |   5
     1      |   4
     3      |   1
     4      |   1
     5      |   1
```

I can't figure it out - I probably need subqueries, JOINS or UNIONS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace count(*) with sum(l1.score) because sum will add all values based on group by statement

```
SELECT sum(l1.score), l1.question_id, l1.action 
FROM `log` l1
GROUP BY l1.question_id, l1.action
```

With constant scores works on SQL Fiddle (with grouping by question):

```
SELECT 
sum(
  CASE WHEN l1.action = 'downvote_question' THEN -1 
  WHEN l1.action = 'upvote_question' THEN 1 
  ELSE 2 END
) score,
l1.question_id
FROM `log` l1
GROUP BY l1.question_id
```

Comment: there is no such column as score

Comment: but score is based on which criteria on action value?

Comment: yes. the score comes from php constants. so they have to be in the query already.

Comment: try now, it doesn't need grouping by action but only by question to get total score. I forgot to add comparison in case because all values was equals to 2 without this

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try this one.

```
SELECT  a.question_id, sum(b.score) totalScore
FROM   `log` a INNER JOIN scoreValue b
          on a.`action` = b.actionname
group by a.question_id
ORDER BY totalScore DESC
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc2c8/2)

Comment: that's pretty nice already except that the scores come from php constants and not another table. should be easy enough to adjust though. i'll give it a try

Comment: you can create table for your constants though :)

Comment: I could - but that would mean, I would have to adjust scores in two places whenever scores would be changed - so I'd prefer storing them in one place.

Comment: it is better to store them in db, and just fetch them from php on each load. cuz storing it in future in your php file it's not a good idea.

Comment: @Horen you would have more work to do if the constants are on your PHP file. but it still depends within you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(SCORE), l1.question_id, l1.action 
FROM `log` l1
GROUP BY l1.question_id, l1.action
```

is it what you want to?

upd: in your code on fidel, there is no such column as score, but i think it wont be a problem to create a tabel with action | score and join it to sum(score)

Comment: the score comes from php constants and has to be added to the query. For now we could hard code it